# maven-assembly plugin error

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

maven-assembly plugin exports and executable jar called `escomled-machine-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. But when I try to run the jar, it gives me an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [appContext.xml]

My `pom.xml` file:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version> 3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
...

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>

                <configuration>
                        <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>

                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.escomled.machinelearning.ml.Escomled_Streams_H2O_ML</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My `appContext.xml` file:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd ">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.escomled" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.escomled.*" />
    <import resource="classpath*:config/blackBoard.xml" />
    <task:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///home/escomled/escomled_server/config/escomled.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="blackboard" class="com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl">
        <property name="hazelcastInstance" ref="hazelcastClient" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

NOTE: I tried with maven-shade plugin, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem with your maven assembly plugin, it is with Spring configuration. Check your xml file and look for namespace inclusion in  tag on begging. Something like this. Also check if you have all spring jars

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: I will edit the questing with the content of my appContext.xml

Comment: Is Spring Transaction your only dependency from Spring? If it is add Spring-context module.

Comment: I added the spring-context and the spring-core and again the same error shows

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl] for bean with name 'blackboard' defined in class path resource [appContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl `      I changed the versions of the modules and now this error shows

Comment: Your BlackboardImpl class is not in the classpath. Are you using multiple modules for this app? If yes add dependencies, if no then try changing component scan path.

Comment: I have added the dependencies and now I'm back to the first error.